# How Do I Print out 1 if a user guessed one of the four digits in a variable

Tags: python

I am coding a little program that basically generates a random 4 digit number but as always I'm stuck once again.

If a user was supposed to enter part of the random 4 digit number how would I say that one of the numbers they got was correct.

Example

Number = 2142

Guess = 2353

You can see the first number is the same as the actual number. How would I get it to say "WRONG, You only got 1 number correct"

Help would be much appreciated

Comment: What are the steps you'd take to do it manually (without a computer)?

Comment: I don't understand mate?

Comment: First solve it manually, on paper. Then pick out the data structures in python that might be useful to hold the number and the guess. Write as much of the program as you can, and let us know if there are any parts that you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

You can have two  separate arrays or lists to store the digits of program generated number and the guessed number. Later you can compare the array elements to check whether there is any match. If a match occurs, you can increment a counter variable

```
def getDigits(nums):
    numbers=[]
    num=int(nums)
    while num != 0:
        d = num%10
        numbers.append(d)
        num=num/10
    return numbers

num1 = random.randint(1000,9999)
print num1
print "Enter a 4 digit number"
guess = raw_input()
print guess
count = 0
list1=getDigits(num1)
list2=getDigits(guess)
for i in range(0,4):
    #print i
    if list1[i]==list2[i]:
        count+=1
if count==0:
    print("Your guess is wrong")
else:
    print ("You got only " +str(count)+ " number correct")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
<input name="guessing" placeholder="enter your guess">
<button type="submit">Submit Button</button>
</form>

    if (isset($_POST['guessing'])) {
     $random_number = rand(5);
    if ($_POST['guessing'] === $random_number) {
    echo "You have successfully guessed the correct number"
    }
    else { 
    echo "You have guessed incorrectly. Please try your request again";
    }

else {
 $error = 'You cannot submit a blank guess';
}
```

NOTE* This is free hand, and have not tested it. However, it should help steer you onto the right track as to what exactly you're doing.